# How do I pull data from one cell to another using matching info in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, spreadsheet, microsoft-excel-2016

So, let me try to explain what I need. I have two different workbooks of data. I need to match info from "WB1 Column B" to "WB2 Column A". If there is a match, I need to pull the info from the same row as the matched data in "WB2 Column A" but from "WB2 Column D" and plug that info into the the original row in "WB1 Column C".

Does that make sense? If so, is there a way to do this?

Comment: Vlookup or INDEX/MATCH

Comment: try out this, https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2015/08/26/excel-compare-two-columns-matches-differences/

Comment: Cool, I've got the INDEX/MATCH function working, but what if I want to check multiple columns for the reference, lookup_value, and lookup_array information?

Comment: The easiest way to handle multiple criteria which may change from timt ot time is to make a helper column.  (Make a cell that combines or checks all the criteria for the row. )

Answer (score 0):

That's exactly what the `VLOOKUP` function is for. Suppose your data begins in row 1 of each worksheet, then in WB1!C1 you would insert the following formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(B1, 'WB2'!A:D, 4, FALSE)
```

You could then copy-paste it to the entire C column.

The first argument to `VLOOKUP` tells Excel what value are you looking for in some other sheet (or other part of the same sheet).

The second is the search (and return) range - Excel will try to find the specified value in the first column of this range (in this case, the A column of WB2), if it finds it, then it will return a value in the same row in any column in the range (see next argument).

The third argument tells which column of the search range has the return value you want - in this case it is the fourth (D, as the range begins in column A).

The final argument should (in my experience) be `FALSE` in most cases, meaning that you are only interested in exact matches. It must be `TRUE` only if you are searching in ordered data and want the value that is closest to whatever value you are looking for.